# Routing error that makes no sense...to me anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Ok here is this generic error message being displayed in the browser I'm receiving when I click a particular link:

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"timesheets", :incident_id=>nil}

Here is the code for the page that contains the link (including the path to create the new record)

```
<div style="float:left;padding:25px;">
<p><%= link_to "Add a Command Officer", new_incident_timesheet_command_officer_path %></p>
</div>
```

Before I click the link the browser url reads as follows:

localhost:3000/incidents/197/timesheet/edit

And the above browser url makes total sense.

When I hover my mouse over the link to "Add a Command Officer" it says at the bottom of the browser:
localhost:3000/incidents/197/timesheets/command_officers/new

But when I click it I get the routing error I mentioned at the top.  Here is the code from the Command_Officers_controller and the routing file.

I believe I've included all the required info for someone to help me out but if I'm missing something let me know.  Thanks for the help

Routes.rb

```
root :to => "incidents#index"

resources :users
resources :profiles

resources :incidents do

resource :mat_list
member do
post :send_notice
end
member do
get :changestatus
end



resource :timesheet do
    resources :command_officers
    resources :fire_chiefs
    resources :fire_fighters
    resources :safety_officers
    resources :emts
    resources :hazmat_specialists
    resources :command_vehicles
    resources :engines
    resources :emergency_supports
    resources :hazmat_units
    resources :field_units
    resources :pumpers
    resources :tankers
    resources :rescue_units
    resources :ladder_truck75s
    resources :ladder_truck150s
end
end


resource :session do
  member do
  get :resetpass
  post :resetpass
 end
end
```

command_officers_controller.rb

```
def new
   @command_officer = CommandOfficer.new
   @timesheet = Incident.find(params[:incident_id]).timesheet

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
   end
end

# GET /command_officers/1/edit
def edit
   @command_officer = CommandOfficer.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /command_officers
# POST /command_officers.xml
def create
   # @new_command_officer = CommandOfficer.new(params[:command_officer])
  @timesheet = Incident.find(params[:incident_id]).timesheet
      @command_officer = @timesheet.command_officer.build(params[:command_officer])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @command_officer.save
               format.html { redirect_to(edit_incident_timesheet_path, :notice => 'Command officer was successfully created.') }
    else
        flash[:error] = "What happened?"
        format.html { render :new }
        end
end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to generate some link on that next page, but the incident_id you are passing to rails is nil.  Check your view/controller and remove/fix the offending code.

More generally, learn how to read the stack trace that rails gives you so you can track these down yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but part of the problem is that this application used to work fine.  But I had to update the version of ruby and rails on my computer and now code that used to work is broke in some areas.  Admittedly I'm not the best programmer and I'm a little leery about "fixing" code that wasn't really broke to begin with.  But I'll try and read the rails stack to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Read through the stack and found the problem.  Thanks for the simple yet effective advice.

Answer (score 1):

You did a nested route but didn't pass the incident id, if you have a instance variable called `@incident`, you could do it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Add a Command Officer", new_incident_timesheet_command_officer_path(@incident) %>
```